# How to hide a panel by clicking on dropdown menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown menu and it has a set of items.I want to hide a particular panel when i am clicking on a dropdown menu.

Below is my c# code and my panel is designed in asp.net.

I want to disable panel `XII` when i was clicking on dropdown list item `Not Applicable` in panel `X`

```
 protected void ddsscboard_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {

            string sscpanel = ddsscboard.SelectedItem.Text;
            panelshow(sscpanel);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    public void panelshow(string sscpanel)
    {
        if (sscpanel == "Not Applicable")
            XII.Visible = false;
        else
            lblmsg.Text = sscpanel;
    }

}
```

panel:-

Class X

```
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Board</label> 
                                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddsscboard" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddsscboard_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                                          <asp:ListItem>Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
                                          <asp:ListItem>SSC</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>CBSC</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem>ICSC</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                                         </asp:DropDownList>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Complition Month</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtssccomplitionmonth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>

                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Complition Year</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtssccomplitionyear" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Marks Obtained</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtsscmarksobtained" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Total Marks</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtssctotalmarks" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Upload File</label>
                                         <asp:FileUpload ID="sscfile"  runat="server" />
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                          </div>
                        <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                       </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
               </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
                <asp:Panel ID="XII" runat="server" CssClass="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Class XII
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">

                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Board</label>
                                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddhscboard" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                                          <asp:ListItem>Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
                                          <asp:ListItem>HSC</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>CBSC</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem>ICSC</asp:ListItem>
                                           <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                                         </asp:DropDownList>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Complition Month</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txthsccomplitionmonth" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Complition Year</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txthsccomplitionyear" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Marks Obtained</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txthscmarksobtained" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Total Marks</label>
                                       <asp:TextBox ID="txthsctotalmarks" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Upload File</label>
                                         <asp:FileUpload ID="hscfile"  runat="server" />
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the AutoPostBack attribute in your DropDownList to true. Note you may also want to establish a blank ListItem so "Not Applicable" is not Selected by default:

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddsscboard" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddsscboard_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Not Applicable</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>SSC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>CBSC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ICSC</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```